# Are there any benefits of reading each field async from a SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ado.net

Is there any gain in reading the fields asynchronously?

Say if I have the following:

```
SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    try
    {
        if (reader.IsDBNull(COL_NAME))
        {
            continue;
        }

        user = new User();
        user.Id = reader.GetInt32(COL_ID);
```

**Would there be any real world benefit by using `IsDBNullAsync` and `GetInt32Async` etc?**

Comment: I've never thought of doing that, but it seems to me an obvious No.  Since you've already read the data its just a matter of pulling it out of memory.

Comment: @DanielGimenez That's what I'm thinking too. I wonder why they are there.

Comment: @DanielGimenez the data isn't *always* in memory; in `SequentialAccess`, this explicitly is not the case

Comment: Not so obvious I guess thanks @MarcGravell

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After some peeking at reflector, the interesting methods here (`GetFieldValueAsync<T>`, `IsDBNullAsync`, and the `internal` method `GetBytesAsync`) only do "interesting" code for the `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` scenario. So: if you're not using that: don't bother - the row data is already buffered in memory, and `Task<T>` is pure overhead (although it will at least be an already-completed task result, i.e. `Task.FromResult<T>` - which is handled efficiently by `await`, without a context switch).

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/20/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta.aspx   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/07/15/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta-part-2-examples.aspx

Comment: The blogs mentioned by @Kevin seem to be deleted, but they can be found on archive.org, "Using SqlDataReader’s new async methods in .Net 4.5" by Daniel Paoliello [part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221192115/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/20/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta.aspx), [part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20140329091147/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/07/15/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta-part-2-examples.aspx)

Comment: I'm a little confused, when would we use GetFieldValueAsync<T> vs GetType when calling ReadAsync? For example: while(await r.ReadAsync){string productID = await r.GetFieldValueAsync<string>("ProductId");} vs while(await r.ReadAsync){string productID = r.GetString(1);} Thank you.

Comment: @eaglei22 honestly, most of the time sync field access is fine (but prefer async row traversal); off the top of my head, the only compelling case here would be reading multiple large CLOB/BLOB payloads on a single row with sequential mode active, but in the large CLOB/BLOB case, using stream access would seem preferable, making this single example questionable!

Comment: Okay, thank you! That makes a little more sense. I have generally seen and used the synchronous field access when invoking an asynchronous read myself.  A new book I've recently finished reading that uses .Net 8, had a simple ReadAsync example using the GetFieldValueAsync<T> for each field access and through me off a little..  So I wanted to  see what the general consensus for this was. Anyway, thank you again for the quick response!

Answer (score 13):

Repeating what Marc wrote, with a snippet from the official [ADO.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/using-sqldatareaders-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5) - that unfortunately have been moved to Microsoft Blog Archives:

> **Read vs ReadAsync** – It is also a good idea to call ReadAsync: in non-sequential mode this will read in all column data, which can potential span multiple packets, allowing faster access to the column values. In sequential mode ADO.NET will need to finish reading the data for the current row (if it hasn’t been read entirely), and there is the potential for some TDS tokens to sit between rows which can then be read asynchronously.
>
> **IsDBNull and GetFieldValue vs IsDBNullAsync and GetFieldValueAsync** - If you had previously called ReadAsync and are using non-sequential access, then calling the synchronous versions of these methods will provide the best performance since the column data has already been read and processed (so calling the asynchronous method just adds the overhead of wrapping the value in a Task). However, if you called Read in non-sequential access mode, or if you are using sequential access mode, then the decision is much harder as you need to consider how much data you need to read to get to your desired column and how much data that column may contain. If you’ve read the previous column, and the target column is small (like a Boolean, a DateTime or a numeric type) then you may want to consider using a synchronous method. Alternatively, if the target column is large (like a varbinary(8000)) or you need to read past large columns, then using an asynchronous method is much better. Finally, if the target column is massive (like a varbinary(MAX), varchar(MAX), nvarchar(MAX) or XML) then you should consider the new [GetStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetStream_System_Int32_), [GetTextReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.gettextreader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetTextReader_System_Int32_) or [GetXmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getxmlreader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetXmlReader_System_Int32_) methods instead.